# Martingale Strong Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Consider a Probability Space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a Sequence of Random variables such that $X_n \in L^2 \; \; \forall n$ and $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{E[X_j^2]}{j^2} < \infty $$

Consider the Natural Filtration $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$

Assume $E[X_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = 0$

Consider $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n X_j $ .   Show that  $$ \frac{S_n}{n} \xrightarrow{A.S} 0   $$

Thoughts :

If we set $Y_o = 0 $ and $Y_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{X_j}{j}$

Then $\{Y_n\}$ is a Martingale with respect to the Filtration.

If we can show that $Y_n$ converges almost surely to  a finite limit then Kroneckers Lemma implies the result.

My goal here is to obviously use the Martingale Convergence theorem but I'm having a small problem.

I tryed to argue that $Y_n$ is $L^1$ Bounded because $$ E[|Y_n|] \leq \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{E[|X_j|]}{j} \leq \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{E[X^2]}{j^2}   $$

This would prove the result if it were true. However I only know for sure that $$ \|\frac{|X_j|}{j} \|_{L^1} \leq  \|\frac{|X_j|}{j} \|_{L^2} $$

This does not neccesarily imply what I used above.

How do I fix this?

Comment: $||Y_n||_1^2\le ||Y_n||_2^2=\sum||X_j||_2^2/j^2$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  How did you get rid of the cross terms to get the last equality? By cross terms I mean E[X_i X_j] etc . It looks like you considered them to have Expectation 0 though I cant figure out how

Comment: Hint: Kolmogorov's two-series theorem applied to $Y_n$.

Comment: I think I got it. The filtration condition makes it that the cross terms have expectation 0

Comment: Right.${}{}{}{}$ Or seems right to me, anyway

Answer (score 2):

Since the increments of a martingale are orthogonal, the following equality holds: $$\mathbb E\left[Y_n^2\right] =\sum_{j=1} ^n\frac{1}{j^2}\mathbb E\left[X_j^2\right],$$
hence the sequence $\left(Y_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is an $\mathbb L^2$-bounded martingale.